# How to transport 1992 Enfield motorcycle from Goa(India) to London

Tags: india, international-law

I have changed my nationality from Indian to Portuguese and will be shifting to London shortly.  I have a motorcycle out here (a 1992 Enfield Bullet motorcycle) which belonged to my dad.  I would like to take it with me to London.  How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You may get better results by splitting this into two or three questions, and asking on different sites. The topics are physically transporting the motorcycle, getting it through UK customs, and getting it registered for use in the UK.